# Python multi-body animation does not work

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I am stuck with a python animation in which I am trying to animate a system of particles initially arranged in a 2 dimensional hexagonal lattice and gradually spreading out as per rule: `xpos1[i]=xpos1[i]+L/10.0`. If any particle goes out of the window limit, they are brought in through the other side

```
if xpos1[i]>L*3:                    # translate back the particle if it goes out of window limit 0 to L*3
    xpos1[i]=xpos1[i]-L*3
elif xpos1[i]<0:
    xpos1[i]=L*3-xpos1[i]
```

And all the updates of position are stored in two list xpos1 and ypos1. This is done for several time steps.

I wish to visualize the time evolution of the system by turning it to an animation. My code is as follows. I have never done matplotlib animations before and actually copied the 'animation' part from another program where it works fine. But it does not work for mine.

```
from numpy import*
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

sigma=3.4e-10           # dist of closest approach
L=4.8e-10           # lattice constant = sigma*2**0.5 (Let)

xpos1=zeros(18,float)
ypos1=zeros(18,float)

# ~~~~~~~~~~~  Setting up the hexagonal lattice ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
k=0
for x in range(0,6,1):
    for y in range(0,6,1):
        if (x+y)%2==0:
            xpos1[k]=x*L*.5+.25*L
            ypos1[k]=y*L*.5+.25*L
            k=k+1

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~TIME EVOLUTION~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
t = 4.5e-12
iteration=1
while t<=1e-9:
    for i in range(18):
        xpos1[i]=xpos1[i]+L/10.0
        ypos1[i]=ypos1[i]+L/10.0
        if xpos1[i]>L*3:                    # translate back the particle if it goes out of window limit 0 to L*cell
            xpos1[i]=xpos1[i]-L*3
        elif xpos1[i]<0:
            xpos1[i]=L*3-xpos1[i]
        if ypos1[i]>L*3:                    # translate back the particle if it goes out of window limit 0 to L*cell
            ypos1[i]=ypos1[i]-L*3
        elif ypos1[i]<0:
            ypos1[i]=L*3-ypos1[i]
    t = t + 4.5e-12

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ANIMATION ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
def simData():
    for i in range(18):
        x=xpos1[i]
        y=ypos1[i]
        yield x,y


def simPoints(simData):
    x,y= simData[0],simData[1]
    line.set_data(x,y)
    return line
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

line,= ax.plot([],[],'bo',ms=8)
ax.set_ylim(0 , L*3)
ax.set_xlim(0 , L*3)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, simPoints, simData, blit=True ,   interval=200)

plt.show()
```

Can somebody tell me how to make the animation successfully?

Comment: Also when I add the argument `frames=10` it returns `TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'frames'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your animation `update` (and `init` if you have one) must return an `iterable`.

```
def simPoints(simData):
    x, y = simData[0], simData[1]
    line.set_data(x, y)
    return line,            # added a comma to return a tuple
```

You may also need to set `blit=False` if you are on mac os

```
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, simPoints, simData, blit=False, interval=200)
```

### Edit:

Here is a minimum working example that shows 18 random points - you'll have to change the random generation to the pattern you want for the points on your lattice.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

x = np.random.random(18)
y = np.random.random(18)

def simData():
    """updates the points position on your lattice.
    replace with your own code - can call a helper function to accomplish this task 
    """
    x = np.random.random(18)
    y = np.random.random(18)
    yield x, y

def simPoints(simData):
    """initializes the points position on your lattice.
    replace with your own code - can call a helper function to accomplish this task 
    """
    x = np.random.random(18)
    y = np.random.random(18)
    line.set_data(x, y)
    return line,

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

line, = ax.plot(x, y,'bo', ms=8)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, simPoints, simData, blit=False, interval=200)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks @Reblochon, my program now returns some output. But this system has 18 particles , whereas the animation shows only 1.

Comment: I added a minimum working example your animation works now - you are mixing numpy with vanilla list operations in your lattice generation; either can work, but you have to make a choice.

Comment: Why does it say `NameError: name 'x' is not defined` when I run your code?

Comment: Good point. `x` and `y` needed to be defined; I was developing in `Jupyter notebook`, and my kernel already had an `x` and a `y` defined, sorry - I fixed it, it is going to work now.

Comment: I tried to do the animation, according to your advise, but still it does not work. It gives the initial position of the particles and remains stuck there for good. Can you tell me where exactly I am going wrong? I have edited my program.

Comment: Please confirm that the animation works with randomly updated points  as it should (it works on my system). Then the issue is with the way you are updating the point coordinates.

Comment: Yes @Reblochon, I should have mentioned it. The animation works perfectly well with randomly updated points (the program that you wrote)

Comment: Thank you, this is already a good point - I suggest that you post a new precise question regarding the update of your data, with a clear description of what the problem is and what it should be doing instead. I'll take a look at it. in the mean time, you may be interested by this: [how to accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235), and this  [why accepting answers is important](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Comment: Yeah sure! Thanks.